# Objective C, Difference between NSSting with "alloc" and without "alloc"

Tags: objective-c

```
 NSString *s1 = @"string1";
 // NSString *s2 = [[NSString alloc]stringWithFormat:@"string2"];
 NSString *s2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"string2"];
```

I know this is pretty basic concept but I am not 100% clear with this.

First one doesn't allocate a memory address and send one allocates a memory address...
Also second one increases the reference count of the variable but not the first one...
Even though I understand the concept but don't know the situation when I should use the first one or the second one..

When should I use the first one ? also when should use for the second one?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Fixed your code as per John's observation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never use the second one - `+stringWithFormat:` is a class method.  Including your first example, you have basically 3 choices:

```
NSString *s1 = @"string1";
NSString *s2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"string2"];
NSString *s3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"string3"];
```

`s1` in this case is a pointer to a constant string.  `s2` and `s3` both point to new strings that you've created, but `s2` has been retained for you, and `s3` has been autoreleased.  If you just need a temporary object, the autoreleased object `s3` or the constant object `s1` are good choices.  If you need to keep the string around, you should use `s2` (actually now that I think about it `s1` will work in this case too - it's not really idiomatic, though).

You can make `s1` or `s3` equivalent to `s2` by sending them a `retain` message.  You could also turn `s2` into an equivalent object by sending it an `autorelease` message.

Answer (score 8):

Carl is is right, but there is some subtlety to keep in mind.  Consider this:

```
NSString *s1 = @"string1";
NSString *s2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"string1"];
NSString *s3 = [NSString stringWithString:@"string1"];
NSString *s4 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"string1"];

NSLog(@"ptrs %p %p %p %p", s1, s2, s3, s4);
```

The output is:

```
ptrs 0x1000010c0 0x1000010c0 0x1000010c0 0x100108da0
```

That's right; `s1`, `s2`, and `s3` are all pointing to the same string instance while `s4` ends up being a new instance.  This is because `NSString` detects when a string is being initialized from a constant string and, when perfectly valid to do so, returns the constant string instead of bothering to allocate a new chunk of memory to hold the same thing.  The `stringWithFormat:` case is not so optimized likely because all the potential format string processing makes such an optimization both moot and, likely, unnatural to the implementation.

In other words, do *not* assume that two strings are the same or different merely by code inspection or by pointer comparison.  Use `isEqual:` or, better yet, `isEqualToString:`.

Answer (score 1):

A string literal like `@"string1"` (or the `@"string2"` on the second line) is, as you've noted, not an allocation. The string is actually stored as a constant in your executable's data section, just like any constant you've declared. Strings created this way don't really have a reference count; you can send `-retain` and `-release` messages to them and nothing will happen.

Your second line is ill-formed; `+stringWithFormat:` is actually a class method, and it doesn't really make sense to use `+stringWithFormat:` without having any format parameters. In general, just use the string literal form if you don't have a specific reason to use another form. There's no need to allocate a new object if there's already the constant one floating around your application.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use any `...WithFormat:` method if you're just going to pass it a constant string.  No need to parse the format string for the trivial case.

Comment: Not to mention that it'll cause unnecessary allocations!